# Cannot Fetch more than one key arrays from my Info.plist file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, info.plist

i am trying to fetch two arrays against two keys in my Info.plist but instead not getting any data in my output. here is my code.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,0),^{
        NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL"];
        NSDictionary *dTmp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:post]];
        NSMutableArray *OriginalDetailsArray=[dTmp valueForKey:@"Objects"];
        NSMutableArray *OriginalGalleryArray=[dTmp valueForKey:@"gallery"];
        detailsArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [detailsArray addObjectsFromArray:OriginalDetailsArray];
        galleryArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [galleryArray addObjectsFromArray:OriginalGalleryArray];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"%@, %@",detailsArray, galleryArray);
        });
    });
```

Out Put is: You can see there is nothing in the output just empty brackets.

```
 (
), (
)
```

here is my Info.plist file. if i remove second array "Gallery" and i only let "Objects" data fetches perfectly. But after adding Second Array it gives empty output.

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Objects</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>propid</key>
<integer>233</integer>
<key>title</key>
<string>101 Perthshire Private</string>
<key>type</key>
<string>For Sale</string>
<key>price</key>
<string>$899,900</string>
<key>bed</key>
<string>2</string>
<key>bath</key>
<string>3</string>
</dict>
</array>
</dict>

<dict>
<key>gallery</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>imageurl</key>
<string>
/images/23330.jpg
</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>imageurl</key>
<string>
/images/23333.jpg
</string>
</dict>
<dict>
<key>imageurl</key>
<string>
/images/23339.jpg
</string>
</dict>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I see no PHP is this code

Comment: sorry. please view now.

Comment: can you please give me any idea how can i correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plist data formot are wrong. Please put below code on your php file and check it.

```
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Objects</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>propid</key>
                <integer>233</integer>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>101 Perthshire Private</string>
                <key>type</key>
                <string>For Sale</string>
                <key>price</key>
                <string>$899,900</string>
                <key>bed</key>
                <string>2</string>
                <key>bath</key>
                <string>3</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>gallery</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>imageurl</key>
                <string>/images/23330.jpg</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>imageurl</key>
                <string>/images/23333.jpg</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>imageurl</key>
                <string>/images/23339.jpg
                </string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try Below Code, I got Result.

NSArray *arrayObjects = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dictRoot objectForKey:@"Objects"]];

NSArray *arrayGallery = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dictRoot objectForKey:@"gallery"]];

```
NSLog(@"%@",arrayObjects); 
NSLog(@"%@",arrayGallery);
```

Comment: same result. Empty

Comment: Your plist data formot are wrong. send me your email id i will mail you proper format of your data file.